# Why my PrintWriter is not sending data to server?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android application. Android app(client) will connect with pc(server) and share data. Right now I can establish connection successfully but 
I  can't send data. Here is my Java file that has all the logic to establish connection and send data.

***ServerConnection.java***

```
public class ServerConnection  {

    private static  int SERVER_PORT = 1100;
    private static  String SERVER_IP = "192.168.43.7";
    private boolean isConnected=false,connectionDone=false;
    private boolean mouseMoved=false;
    Context context;
    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public void startConnection(String port , String ip){
        SERVER_IP = ip.toString();

        ConnectPhoneTask connectPhoneTask = new ConnectPhoneTask();
        connectPhoneTask.execute(SERVER_IP);
    }


    public void sendDataToServer(String text){
        try {
            if(isConnected) {
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true); //create output stream to send data to server

            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("remotedroid", "Error while creating OutWriter", e);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error: while creating OutWriter "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(out!=null){
            out.println(text);
        }
        else{
            Log.e("check" , "Something is wrong here");
        }
    }

    public class ConnectPhoneTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            boolean result = true;

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(params[0]);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);//Open socket on server IP and port

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("remotedroid", "Error while connecting", e);
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {
            isConnected = result;
            try {
                if(isConnected) {
                    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true); //create output stream to send data to server

                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e("remotedroid", "Error while creating OutWriter", e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this fragment will initiate connection and send data(by calling `sendDataToServer(String text)` method).

***LogIntoServer.java***

```
public class LogIntoServer extends Fragment {

    private EditText ipadr,portadr;
    private Button connect,disconnect;
    ServerConnection serverConnection;
    String SERVER_IP ;
    String SERVER_PORT;
    PrintWriter out;


    public LogIntoServer() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log_into_server, container, false);
        ipadr      = v.findViewById(R.id.ipadr);
        portadr    = v.findViewById(R.id.portadr);
        connect    = v.findViewById(R.id.connect);
        disconnect = v.findViewById(R.id.disconnect);

        serverConnection = new ServerConnection();
        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 SERVER_IP = ipadr.getText().toString();
                 SERVER_PORT = portadr.getText().toString();
                 serverConnection.startConnection(SERVER_PORT , SERVER_IP);
                 serverConnection.sendDataToServer("Connection Successful");
            }
        });

        disconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                serverConnection.sendDataToServer("exit");
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}
```

If I double click the connect button then it will send "Connection Successful" for one time only. Please help.

Comment: The code doesn't look thread safe, where `out` is re-initialized during multiple click events.  Are there any errors?

Comment: No there is not any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these fields to `AsyncTask`; probably even as `static`:

```
private boolean isConnecting = false;
private boolean isConnected = false;
```

and set these to `true` & `false`, whenever the socket status changes

then it doesn't matter anymore, how often the button will be clicked.

code from `sendDataToServer()` should possibly run `onPreExecute()`.

that extra class surrounding the `AsyncTask` also is a mess;

better construct it directly - with IP, port and message.

you got some `OutputStreamWriter` but never write to the stream;

besides this barely is any `onPostExecute` code in there.